# How to perform path compression in a tree based partition structure?

Tags: java, path, compression

I am very new to java so need a little help understanding path compression specifically in a tree-based partition union structure. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you don't understand about path compression?

Comment: I understand that it is a shortcut to a root node in a tree when using find. What I wanted to see was the pseudo-code to do so.

Comment: You mentioned abou union find data structure.  Please read more about it